# In Android, what's the difference between "backstack" and "task"?

Tags: android, kotlin, task, back-stack

I can't understand why there are two terms.  It seems redundant that a all of the activities exist in a task, and all activities exist in a backstack, and the task "uses" the backstack to organize the activities.  Did someone drop Occam's razor down the drain, or are these actually two distinct entities that different parts of the operating system have to deal with separately?

I've searched around google and some forums and haven't found a satisfactory answer.  I know it seems frivolous, but this is a real question that matters to me; I have a tiny informational digestive tract that can't take in anything new until the present stuff is fully metabolized.  I'm new to code, and it's hurting my brain.  Please assist.

Comment: Did you review [the documentation page that explicitly explains this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)?

Comment: @dominicoder I did, and it didn't address the redundancy.  Is it fair to say that the activity at the top of the stack isn't included in the "back"stack, and that the "task" consists of the full stack of (focused activity + backstack)?

Comment: Forget about actual Activities - the system can kill any Activity that is not in the foreground at any time, but the backstack - the _representation_ of which Activities the user was using and in what order - will remain in tact as part of the Task. So the Task _has_ a "backstack" that it uses to track the user's navigation, which includes an entry for the focused (top-most) activity.

Comment: "Back stack" does also include the top activity (the one that is currently on screen if the task is currently in the foreground).

Comment: @dominicoder Since the backstack is _part_ of the Task, what other parts does a Task contain that a backstack does not?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. You could try searching through the source code to see how they model a "task" and a "backstack" and how they relate.

Comment: @dominicoder Where do I locate that?  I'm using android studio.

Comment: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject

Answer (score 0):

1. Task is a set of activities activities that the user interacts with when performing a certain action or workflow.
2. Backstack is a stack of activities that the user has navigated through **within a particular task**. When the user moves from one activity to another, the previous activity is pushed onto the back stack. When the user presses the back button, the previous activity is popped off the stack and becomes the current activity.

For example, you opens Twitter app and Android creates a task for it. Then you see feed and click on some tweet. Activity with some tweet opens. So, in this task there is a backstac with 2 activities in it.

So, to answer your question, the task and the back stack are two separate concepts, but they are closely related. The task represents the overall context in which the user is interacting with a set of activities, while the back stack represents the user's history of navigation within that context.

Comment: What does a task have that the backstack does not?  Is there actually a separate layer of code for each?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the task *contains* a back stack of Activities, but it would be confusing to talk about back stacks of tasks that are not currently on screen.

Task is the technical term actually used in the code. You don't need to precisely define back stack, so these terms are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: What does affinity mean in this context?

Comment: Task being the term used in the code, is backstack just a way for the programmer to conceptualize the relation of components within the task, but not actually a distinct "thing" from task as far as execution of the code goes?

Comment: Well, really, task affinity is defined per Activity, not per task, so I was wrong about that.  I think they just use the term back stack to help conceptualize it, yes. "Back stack" seems to be used more when they're talking about how it's an ordered stack of activities, and Task is only used when they talk about starting new tasks and switching between them, etc. Conceptually it would feel weird to talk about a "back" stack of a task that isn't currently on screen, since those are not the Activities you will see if you start backing up.

Comment: I guess I'm too new to be trusted to upvote answers, but thank you for your responses.